# Grid view-Clickable and Expandable row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i make the rendered grid view row clickable and expandable on click of a row.

The row when click must expand down with few text fields.Then when click again must collapse.
Is this possible in Rendered Grid view.I want to populate database records in this grid view,hence i can not use html table for this purpose.

Appreciate ur help

Comment: GridView's not going to like that.  You're better off with a Repeater and CollapsiblePanel: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx

Comment: In Repeater is it possible that every row will retrieve the values from database and on click of that row show a panel